# how to include a file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Hy, I have a page on my site, with the name of hotels. here is the code of the hotel page.

here is my controller:

```
function country_holiday(){
    $data['hotels']= $this->Travel->holiday();
    $this->load->view('hotels', $data);
}
```

here is my model:

```
function holiday(){
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('holidays_hotel_2');
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->limit(16);   
    $query= $this->db->get();                   
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I am getting my required data on hotel page and its working fine, I want to include this hotel page into my another page(hotelling program).

I used  where i want to placed that hotel in hotelling program page, but it did not show up any detail except the html of hotel page. what should i need to do. Any Idea??

Comment: you want to show the same hotel details in another page let me clarify this is what exactly  you are asking??

Comment: yes exactly I want to show hotel details

Comment: $data['hotels']= $this->Travel->holiday(); use this line in some other view you will get the same details in that page also

Comment: @HarrisKhan Can you explain this please

Comment: like we include header <?php include('header.php'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, you want to include your hotel page into hotelling page. Which means you want to call a view inside another view. Yes you can.

In your controller,

```
function country_holiday(){
    $data['hotels']= $this->Travel->holiday();
    $this->load->view('hotelling', $data);
}
```

in your view (hotelling.php),

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php $this->load->view('hotels', $hotels); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But i'm not sure about the downside of doing this. But it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to include a controller into another controller just like a inheritance,so that you can use parent controller functionalities automatically without writing an extra code.So for that you just have to extend your controller with the parent controller and require its path in the child controller and you can use their function using $this.

```
require('application/controllers/Hotel.php'); /*You have to define the path of the file*/
class Hotelling extends Hotel  /*Then your hotelling controllers extends hotel controller*/
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->country_holiday();
    }
}
```